# Manual phpMyAdmin Installation - Windows Server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have manually installed PHP, and Apache on a Windows server which had an existing MySQL database installed on it.

I am now trying to install phpMyAdmin, but with no luck thus far.

When going to localhost/phpMyAdmin I get the index of the phpMyAdmin directory instead on it displaying the usual phpMyAdmin login screen etc.

Have I missed something along the way?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it work correctly now. Updated the following in my Apache configuration file: DirectoryIndex index.php index.html home.pl index.cgi